# add suffix to file name while uploading on azure blob storage manually by user

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using azure blob storage specifically containers to fetch files and load it in snowflake. The files that I am getting on blob are uploaded by CA department people and that process is manual since they are not in technology much. Sometimes they change the data in same file and upload it back with same name and my snowpipe just can't fetch the data since the file name is same, i understand that I can't force snowpipe to just fetch same data but I am thinking if somehow i can add suffix to file name as soon as user uploads it on blob like _1, _2 to make the name different to snowpipe to load. I am not expert in azure just asking to get some solution of my problem.

Comment: Are your users using some 3rd party software to upload the files or using a custom application for that? In case of latter, can you share the code for uploading?

Comment: users are loading files using azure storage explorer manually